# heroku buildpack for installing libmosquitto

Tags: heroku, buildpack

I'm trying to create a small [buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-api) for a [Heroku](http://heroku.com) app that uses a [MQTT](http://mqtt.org) broker. To establish a communication channel with the broker I use the [mosquitto](https://github.com/xively/mosquitto) gem, which itself require me to install a package on the system and build it.

The gem has pretty simple instructions:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pkg-config cmake openssl libc-ares-dev

wget http://mosquitto.org/files/source/mosquitto-1.3.1.tar.gz
tar xzf mosquitto-1.3.1.tar.gz
cd mosquitto-1.3.1
cmake .
sudo make install
```

I need a buildpack that would do just that on a Heroku [cedar](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar) app. I gave it a shot [heroku-buildpack-mosquitto](https://github.com/rolandjitsu/heroku-buildpack-mosquitto), but I failed and I get an error. I'm not a shell expert and I have no clue what I'm doing.

I use the following `.buildpack`, together with [heroku-buildpack-multi](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi):

```
https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-apt.git
https://github.com/rolandjitsu/heroku-buildpack-mosquitto.git
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git
```

And the `Aptfile` for [heroku-buildpack-apt](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-apt.git):

```
pkg-config
cmake
openssl
libc-ares-dev
```

I get the following error:

```
/tmp/buildpack_23cdb652-73cc-461b-b70f-ec3f386ebee1/bin/compile: line 44: /tmp/buildpack5JP7B/bin/detect: No such file or directory
```

I would appreciate any help since I am not capable of figuring this out myself :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `bin/detect` script in your buildpack.
This is the script that confirms whether the code you pushed is, in our case, a Ruby project. So you probably want to try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# bin/detect <build-dir>

if [ -f $1/Gemfile ]; then
  echo "Ruby" && exit 0
else
  echo "no" && exit 1
fi
```

Comment: that is not the issue anymore, I have managed to get that working. Now it seems like the `cmake` command is not there, even though I install with `apt` the packages that are needed for doing the build. I am kind of stuck and I have no clue how to fix it. I have added more description about the error and I have updated the repo.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't update the question like this. The original question was about missing `bin/detect` script and I answered that part. Now you have changed the question and my answer looks totally unrelated, this is not going to help other people who face similar issues.

Comment: If I were you, I would revert the question to what it was and post a new one about the cmake issues. Perhaps you should just ask "How do I install cmake on Heroku?" and describe what you tried.

Comment: Done, I have changed it :)